# SqlBulkCopy keeps on throwing connection forcibly closed exception

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to insert around 700 rows using `SqlBulkCopy` but I keep getting this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Earlier I was using `using` statement for both `SqlConnection` and `SqlBulkCopy` objects creation then I found this post

[SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer() keep getting "connection is closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272645/sqlbulkcopy-writetoserver-keep-getting-connection-is-closed)

and tried taking both of them out of using statement but it is still returning the same error.

The other thing is, when I try it for few records it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: May we see your code?

Comment: Attach SQL Server Profiler and capture the error event. Also post the full exception ToString.