# SQL connection closes during SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to use SqlBulkCopy to import data into a temp table.

```
private bool CreateTempTable(IDbConnection conn, byte[] fileByteArray, string tempTableName)
{
        try
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileByteArray);

            using (var reader = new CsvReader(stream, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // Bulk insert the data into a temporary table.
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection)conn))
                {
                    // Import the data into the temp table
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tempTableName;
                    bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 20000;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, $"CreateTempTable(): Exception while creating the TempTable \"{tempTableName}\" - {ex.Message}");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

This method is called within another method that runs as async. The connection is passed and maintained by code that looks similar to this:

```
private async Task<bool> ConsumeAsyn(byte[] fileByteArray, string tempTableName)
{
        using (var conn = (SqlConnection)OpenConnection())
        {
            if (CreateTempTable(conn, fileByteArray, tempTableName))
            {
                // success
            }
            else
            {
                // fail
            }
        }
}
```

This is basically how the ConsumeAsync is being called:

```
    public async Task<bool> ProcessNextAsync2()
    {
        try
        {
            isIdle = false;

            string filePath = ImportFilePickupPath + "\\" + Filename;
            byte[] inStream = await LoadImportFileAsync(filePath);

            bool consumeSuccess = await Consume(inStream, "##TempTable");

            if (consumeSuccess)
            {
                // Delete the file
                DeleteImportFile(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                // Rescedule job
            }

            isIdle = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isIdle = true;
        }

        return isIdle;
    }
```

If I use a small record set, of about a 100 rows in my csv, then everything works. The problem is if I have thousands of records, then the connection gets terminated during the bulk import process.

How can I pass the connection to the method and ensure that it remains open till the bulk import completes?

Comment: why not let the CreateTempTable take care of the connection lifetime?

Comment: Because there are other operations that must happen before and after the temp table has been created that required the same open connection or the ##temp data will go bye bye.

Comment: how do you call ConsumeAsyn? can you share the code?

Comment: Sounds like a timeout on CreateTempTable. It might be a better idea to keep the data in memory before calling CreateTempTable or buffer/paginate smaller number of records at a time.

Comment: @JReno, the csv files could potentially contain millions of records. Bulk import can import those record within seconds. We can't keep those in memory because we could run the risk of running out of said memory. The data is streamed into the temp data table and we can process after the import has happened.

Comment: @anber you're keeping two copies of the data in memory, one in inStream and one in the MemoryStream.

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori The SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout defines how long the client waits around to connect to the SQL Server. Once the connection is established it has no effect. In this case the SqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout property is the one that matters and, according to OP's example code, it's set to 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Comment: OK, I think I found the problem. I'm using a third party NuGet package to manage my DB connection. I think it's what's closing my connection because if I open my own SqlConnection, then the SqlBulkCopy works great. I'll just have to be careful not to leave connections open :)

Comment: @anber Looking at your code it's not immediately obvious as to why that should be the case. If you could document the problem and resolution in an Answer to your own Question that will would be extremely helpful to anyone else encountering the same problem in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an answer, maybe not, but perhaps need to keep your IDisposables (at least/especially the SqlConnection) outside of the async tasks.

This answer over here makes it sound like .NET considers the IDiposables to be out of scope and so disposes them while you're still trying to use them:

[SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer() keep getting "connection is closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24272920/390122)

Comment: I agree with your assessment but I'm not so sure as to why it happens. I have been able to solve the problem by getting rid of all async calls. This code was meant to run as a service so async wasn't really necessary. I also dropped my dependency on third party libraries to manage my connections.

Answer (score 1):

I were able to fix my problem by dropping support on a third party nuget lib that were dropping my connections. While it's unclear as to why it was happening, getting rid of all async calls and managing the connections myself seemed to have fixed my issue. Bulk imports was working fine however processing the data from the ##Temp table was slow. I decided to keep it all in memory and process it from there.

```
    private bool Consume(byte[] fileByteArray, IDataProcess dataConsumer)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = OpenConnection())
            {
                // Convert byte Array to a stream
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileByteArray);

                // Create a reader from the stream
                using (var reader = new CsvReader(stream, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    RecordEnumerator enumerator = reader.GetEnumerator();
                    enumerator.MoveNext();
                    do
                    {
                        // Proccess enumerator.Current with dataConsumer

                    } while (enumerator.MoveNext());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

We run the risk of running out of memory but until we get a faster approach, this will have to do.

Comment: Did you look into why the ##temp table appears slow? It is a table like any other, so any lookups and joins on it will benefit from having covering indexes. Also if it has `char` or `varchar` columns in it, as opposed to `nchar` or `nvarchar`, any `collation` differences between tempdb and your user database could be causing a bunch of implicit collation conversions and slow down character/string comparisons.